# Query jbatch tables

Tags: jakarta-ee, jbatch

JBatch writes job instance execution data into tables. For my application I manually created them and configured the application server to use them. That works fine. However, since the batchstatus of some executioninstances is FAILED I would like to know why and hence would like to query those tables. However, some of the data is stored as bytea (postgres). How can I query that data so it returnes readable data? How can I find out about why a specific job instance failed?

Comment: Are you running in Glassfish?   Did you try viewing the **JobRepository** in the **Admin Console** as described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/batch-1965499.html) (or using the CLI, also described there)?    That can give you a rough idea of where the job failed... e.g. which step it failed on and the step-level status and metrics.    For more detailed diagnostics, you might want/need to instrument your application itself with logging.   You could also consider turning on trace of the jbatch runtime using logging pattern `com.ibm.jbatch.*`.

Comment: Viewing the table data directly isn't likely to help much on top of the above (though it does contain the persistent user data which you really won't be able to access otherwise).  Most of the data could be more easily viewed with the methods above.  Though the DDL is [here](https://github.com/WASdev/standards.jsr352.jbatch/blob/master/com.ibm.jbatch.container/src/main/resources/ddls/jsr352-postgresql.ddl), the data persisted doesn't map 1-1 to externally accessible (via API) data.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Haven't seen somebody answered. Yes, I added more logging information through the application itself which helped. Apart from that it seems that Payara commits all successful steps when an exception occurs before reaching the end of a batch. Doesn't disturb but is not what was expected.